# Sql Server for each row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm using Sql Server and triggers.

In the past I used Oracle and triggers.
In Oracle there is a functionality FOR EACH ROW triggers.

Sql Server 2000 and 2005 doesn't support this but which version does this support.

Regards

Comment: I would like to know if Sql Server this in other versions supported.

Comment: [Use the inserted and deleted tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300(v=sql.105).aspx). They contain all rows which were deleted, inserted or updated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent in SQL Server. You only have the INSERTED and DELETED tables to work with, which you have to explicitly match up to get the row-for-row correlation.  In certain cases where the table does not have an immutable GUID or identity column (surrogate key), it can be impossible to match them up.

It's up to the design of the schema to make sure there is such an identifier if a trigger will need to be employed, or to ensure that updates that involve the identifier key changes can ONLY occur a single row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

No, SQL Server does not have `FOR EACH ROW` triggers. You need to inspect the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables - either perform set-based operations on them, or use cursors to iterate over them.

Comment: So even Sql Server 2012 doesn't support this